# How to set default datetime format in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, date, datetime, format, datetime-format

I want to fetch data from table by changing date format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss but in output it is dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss by default.

I can achieve this by using CONVERT function but this is to be applied once for one column but i have many column and tables so I don't want to write this for every column.
I want to set the datetime format as default so even for simple select * query it will be showing formatted date.

```
CREATE TABLE dateFormatss (dateFormatOption int, dateOutput datetime)

insert into dateFormatss (dateFormatOption, dateOutput) values ('1', '2019-12-31 14:47:48')

 select 
   [dateFormatOption],
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,[dateOutput],120) as dateOutput  from dateFormatss 

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

select * from dateFormatss
```

OutPut:

```
dateFormatOption        dateOutput
    1               2019-12-31 14:47:48

dateFormatOption        dateOutput
    1               31.12.2019 14:47:48
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default language in the SQL server properties to apply the change server wide but this will affect all databases within the server. You can't alter the datetime format as you desire to individuals columns, tables or even databases. SET DATEFORMAT only changes the session date format.

You may have to resort to using views on the tables to do the convert as you have demonstrated.

Other options include changing the OS region settings, changing the SQL server setting or create a new user and use dbcc useroptions

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/

perhaps also have a look at microsoft documentation for Date and Time Data Types and Functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Changing the OS region helped but if I change the system it again creates problem. I was searching for option in query so that the code will run perfectly on every system. By the way Thanks for answer it also helped ..!!!